# A manga where the main character has a system that tells him to get talented disciples and then create a sect

Tags: story-identification, manga

In this manga the main character is at first useless, but a system activates and directs him to look for talented disciples and after he did that he had to find a suitable place to create sect.

He went to a mountain that led to another small world/dimension which was blocked from the outside world by a fog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [The First Ancestor in History](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/historys-number-1-founder) (AKA History's Number 1 Founder).

> He transmigrated and got a system but Lin Feng’s pressure is as big as
> a mountain. System main quest: Ling Feng creates a school,
> establishing history’s number 1 sect, Ling Feng himself becoming the
> number 1 founder. And so to become history’s number 1 founder, Lin
> Feng started to work hard.
>
> [image]

This image is from the first book, where the main character accidentally activates his system and learns that he is tasked with creating a sect.

[image]